Why is it difficult to compute the number of views a question received after an answer was posted?
I was reading this thread to see how views on answers are calculated and added to the people reached counter. I couldn't understand the reason for this point:


Plus, we can't really even count the views on answers, nor can we count just the views on a question page that came in after a given answer was posted.


Why is it difficult to calculate the number of views a question received after a particular answer was posted?

TL;DR: because they don't write to the database all the views and/or date of each view, they only increment a counter (i.e. a field) by 1 for each view.

Also very much related: Statistic for views over time.

@ShadowWizard it's in the section How it currently works(and why).

The counter currently (t-0) shows X. There is no way to see what the counter was t-1 or t-n for any value of n. And to find views after posting, you need to do conter_at_t_minus_n - counter_at_t_zero (where n is when the length of time the answer has been posted).

@VLAZ I didn't understand what this counter is and where do I find it for a particular question?

@MathGuy https://i.sstatic.net/nuaSnt3P.png the value itself resides in the database. But, again, it's one dimensional. There is no "value at " just "value".

@VLAZ But they could store the value of the ViewCount in the answer record when an answer was posted and then subtract that from the Question ViewCount when calculating the people reached value for each user. That would at least reduce the ViewCount for answers posted years after the original question.

@PeterJames Yes, if you introduce data that is currently missing, you could do that. I don't think "If you solve the problem, then you don't have a problem!" is an acceptable gotcha here.

@VLAZ Yes, going forward it could be fixed. Historically, I guess they could interpolate a value based on the assumption that the views are linear. However, the problem will always be that the ViewCount of a post does not guarantee in any way what exactly was viewed.

@PeterJames I mean, views being linear is also far from the norm. If you are just going to assume that, you don't get data that is much better than the current implementation. They are all going to be wrong. Views typically are highest at the start then peter off. Although activity around the question can change that and "bump" the activity. As can other factors, say, a new version of a software throws an error that there is already a question for. There would be a big increase of views when that happens. Maybe the question only had ~150 views before and then accrued 5000.


Why is it difficult to calculate the number of views a question received after a particular answer was posted?

The data is not there.
View count is tracked on opening a question. It is a numeric value associated with only the question. It is a one dimensional value that you cannot interrogate as "what was the view count at some time".
Here is an example:

Day 1 - question gets posted. It gets 50 views. No answers.
Day 2 - the question gets to 75 views (another 25 views since day 1). Still no answers.
Day 3 - the question gets an answer and the view count is 115 (another 40 since day 2).

At this point in time, we know that

The question has 115 views.
There is an answer.

And this is the only information available in terms of views. There is no information from day 1, or day 2. Only what is there now. Therefore, the answer can have been seen by anywhere between 0 and 115 people. There is no way to extrapolate "since before posting the answer, the view count was X, now it is Y, therefore the answer has Y-X views".
There is an additional problem that there is not even a guarantee that a user who opened the question (and thus increased the view count) also looked at the answer. Here are several scenarios that show the impossibility of tracking views on answers:

a user possible they opened the page, looked at the question and figured it does not help them. Without ever scrolling to the answer section. The question was seen, but not the answer.
a user looked at the question and answer 1 and 2, but not answer 3.
a user downloaded the page to look at later. That will generate one view but the user could have referenced this multiple times.
a user scrolled down the page putting an answer in their viewport but never actually reading it.

As demonstrated, there is no way to track what a user read.

Didn't SE ran an experiment once with "tracking" pixels? Or was this solely for advertising purposes and not for this metric?

@Lino the only tracking pixel think I recall is Update to our Advertising Guidelines (see also: Will the tracking pixels replace the existing advertiser tracking?) - previous to the update retargeting pixels were not allowed, and the update allowed them under some limitation.s Uh, TBH, I don't actually get the difference between "tracking" and "retargeting" pixels. I checked a few descriptions which seem to imply they are different but also claims both identify and monitor a user for marketing purposes.
